TimeSeriesModelFit can't take entire data
Somehow this code doesn't work
data = {126, 131, 129, 127, 131, 126, 132, 132, 133, 132, 131, 128, 
   135, 132, 128, 132, 135, 133, 132, 134, 138, 136, 136, 137, 138, 
   136, 142, 133, 139, 136, 127, 132, 130, 128, 132, 127, 133, 133, 
   134, 133, 132, 129, 136, 133, 129, 133, 136, 134, 133, 135, 139, 
   137, 137, 138, 139, 137, 143, 134, 140, 137, 129, 134, 132, 130, 
   134, 129, 135, 135, 136, 135, 134, 131, 138, 135, 131, 135, 138, 
   136, 135, 137, 141, 139, 139, 140, 141, 139, 145, 136, 142, 139, 
   130, 135, 133, 131, 135, 130, 136, 136, 137, 136, 135, 132, 139, 
   136, 132, 136, 139, 137, 136, 138, 142, 140, 140, 141, 142, 140, 
   146, 137, 143, 140};
TimeSeriesModelFit[data]

It returned the inputted expression. But if I take just some from the data it works just fine
TimeSeriesModelFit[data[[1 ;; 90]]]

I don't know what's happening here and how to use the full data. I tried TemporalData and TimeSeries, but I got the same behavior. I am using WMA 14.1 on Windows 11.
Update: This workaround "solves" the problem, but the result is clearly wrong. In this case, the forecast is too low.
data[[1]] = data[[1]] + 0.000001;
tsm = TimeSeriesModelFit[data];
ListLinePlot[{tsm["TemporalData"], TimeSeriesForecast[tsm, {30}]}]



If you specify a model, it works. E.g.: TimeSeriesModelFit[data, "AR"]["BestFit"]

So, is it a confirmed bug?

Changing the first value data[[1]] = data[[1]] + 0.000001 "solves" the problem, apparently

Please report this bug to support@wolfram.com

Thanks, reported. I will investigate...
